# Avoid Apex Schedule limit

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, limitexception

We have a requirement to launch two schedule apex each hour but we're reaching schedule limits.

I have this piece of code in apex:

```
public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    Datetime now = Datetime.now().addHours(1);
    System.schedule(MyClass.class.getName() + ' ' + generateRandomString(6), '0 30 ' + now.hour() + ' ' + now.day() + ' ' + now.month() + ' ? ' + now.year(), new MyClass());
    }
    AsyncApexJob aaj = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id = :bc.getJobId()];
    System.abortJob(aaj.id);
}
```

I've seen someone posting that including this in my execute

```
public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    Database.executebatch(new MyClass());
    List<CronTrigger> cTriggers = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime FROM CronTrigger WHERE id = :SC.getTriggerId()];
    if (!cTriggers.isEmpty()){ System.abortJob(cTriggers[0].Id); }
}
```

I'll be able to avoid this limits. Is this true? Or is it even a way to achieve this?

Regards,

Comment: Given you are offsetting from "now" and appear to be doing this for a batchable, why not just use System.scheduleBatch?

Comment: Which limit are you encountering?

Comment: @manjit5190 100 schedule jobs limit

Comment: @PhilW Is there a way to control that schedule via System.scheduleBatch has been already configured? So I can avoid relaunching it in my finish method

Comment: If you don't want to relaunch from finish, just manually (or via Apex) do a one-off to set up a recurring scheduled execution of your schedulable/batchable implementation.

Comment: @PhilW Can you attach an example so I can understand it better? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you need the batch executed twice an hour (i.e. at 30 minute intervals) then schedule it **twice**, using `System.schedule`, once with a schedule like `0 0 * * * ? *` and once with a schedule like `0 30 * * * ? *`. This means it will execute at 0 minutes and seconds past each hour and again at 30 minutes and 0 seconds past each hour. The Schedulable/Batchable combined implementation then simply does `Database.executeBatch(this)` to execute its batchable aspect from within `execute(SchedulableContext)`.